# doInBackground gets stuck

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, udp

I'm trying to create a server that uses multiple ports so different data and information can be sent and received with ease, but in my doInBackground method, my code gets stuck on a socket.receive,
Here is my code

```
while( run )
    {
        //GameServerID
        try
        {
            if(gameServerID == null)
            {
                gameServerID = new DatagramSocket( portID );
            }
            //try to receive data
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
            try
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Wait for something to connect");
                gameServerID.receive( packet ); <--GETS STUCK HERE
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );
            Log.d(TAG, data);
            //Send out the ID to the client
            byte[] bufer = new byte[256];
            //Send a message "connect" to the host
            String msg = Integer.toString( players );
            players = players + 1;
            bufer = msg.getBytes();
            InetAddress address;
            //Default ip address of the host
            address = packet.getAddress();
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( bufer, bufer.length , address, portID );
            //Send packet
            gameServerID.send( p );
            addresses.add( address );
        }
        catch (SocketException e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        //Listen for a client to connect
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with I/O");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //GameServerPositions
        try
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Run the gamePositions code");
            if(gamePositions == null)
            {
                gamePositions = new DatagramSocket( portPos );
            }
            //Receive position
            //try to receive data
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
            try
            {
                gamePositions.receive( packet );
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );
            Log.d(TAG, data);
            String[] pos = data.split(":");
            for(int i = 0;i<pos.length;i++)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, pos[i]);
            }
            xValues[ Integer.parseInt( pos[0] ) ] = Integer.parseInt( pos[1] );
            yValues[ Integer.parseInt( pos[0] ) ] = Integer.parseInt( pos[2] );
        }
        catch (SocketException e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        //Listen for a client to connect
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with I/O");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //GameServerSendPos
        try
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Run the gamePositionsSend code");
            String data = "";
            if( gameSendPos == null )
            {
                gameSendPos = new DatagramSocket( portSend );
            }

            //create the string ready to be sent out
            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                if(xValues[i] >= 0)
                {
                    data += i + ":" + xValues[i] + ":" + yValues[i] + ":";
                }
            }

            byte[] bufer = new byte[256];
            bufer = data.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket p = null;

            for(int i = 0;i < addresses.size(); i++)
            {
                if( addresses.get(i) != null )
                {
                    p = new DatagramPacket( bufer, bufer.length , addresses.get(i), portSend );
                    gameSendPos.send( p );
                }
            }

        }
        catch (SocketException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What can I do to stop it from getting stuck, or after so long waiting, just to skip it? Just for more information, when the first client connects, the code works fine, until it reaches the top again and then the socket.received just jams up...

Canvas

Update

I have changed my code into 3 different classes, I start them in my servers while loop like so

```
while( run )
    {
        if(start == true)
        {
            gsID.doInBackground( );
            addresses = gsID.addresses;
            gsPos.addresses = addresses;
            gsPos.doInBackground( );
            gsSendPos.addresses = addresses;
            gsSendPos.positions = gsPos.positions;
            gsSendPos.doInBackground( );
            start = false;
        }
        else
        {
            addresses = gsID.addresses;
            gsPos.addresses = addresses;
            gsSendPos.addresses = addresses;
            gsSendPos.positions = gsPos.positions;
        }
    }
```

But it still once again gets stuck on the gameServerID receive method.

I just changed all my classes to thread, and it works better, but in the later versions of android 4.0+ threads can't be used from the UI, but i'm not sure how I start them from not the UI?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my answer, it gets "stuck" because `receive()` is a blocking IO call that sits and waits for data to be available on the input stream.  This code is in your server so threading should be fine.  On the UI side you could potentially send data to the server from the UI thread if needed (not familiar with Android development).  Also checkout my link on NIO if you want to avoid threading on the server and use non-blocking IO.

Answer (score 2):

From the Javadoc for [DatagramSocket.receive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive%28java.net.DatagramPacket%29):

> This method blocks until a datagram is received

So your code is 'stuck' because it is waiting for data packets to arrive.  This means the client that is connecting to this server/port hasn't yet sent another packet so the socket is blocking by design.

Traditionally if you want to listen on multiple ports at the same time you have two options:

1. Open each blocking socket on a different thread (this won't scale well if you will have large number of clients concurrently due to one client per thread but works fine for a small number of connections)
2. Use NIO which is non-blocking IO for Java

Comment: so in other words? split all of these up into three different classes, that all have doInBackground methods?

Comment: Also how would I use UDP NIO?

Comment: Or one class that you instantiate 3 times and run in 3 separate threads.

Comment: For NIO there is lots of information out there, basically you use `DatagramChannel` + `Selector`.  The `Selector` runs on one thread handling all channels.  Checkout [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html) and [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/datagram-channel.html) as one potential guide.

Comment: NIO is *new* I/O for Java. non-blocking mode is *one* of its options.